# HTML theme jQuery breaking when adding forward slash

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a HTML theme that uses jQuery and the author of the theme is just telling me not to use forward slashes. I can't see how this is breaking from my point of view.

URLs in the main menu are setup like:

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <a href="about-us" class="nav-link">About</a>
</li>
```

I first found the problem when I tried to create a sub folder called case-studies which would have its own html files in. But when ever I add a forward slash to the url like so:

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <a href="/about-us" class="nav-link">About</a>
</li>
```

All jQuery elements on the website break and the console gives me this error:

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /about-us  
        at Function.ga.error (jquery.min.js:2)  
        at ga.tokenize (jquery.min.js:2)  
        at ga.select (jquery.min.js:2)  
        at Function.ga [as find] (jquery.min.js:2)  
        at r.fn.init.find (jquery.min.js:2)  
        at new r.fn.init (jquery.min.js:2)  
        at r (jquery.min.js:2)  
        at r (scrollspy.min.js:1)  
        at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (scrollspy.min.js:1)  
        at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Is this actually the case you can't use forward slashes with jQuery v3.1.1? Any advice or input on this would be fantastic.

Edit https://pastebin.com/AcrYsCqn custom.js

Comment: This is a problem with the logic of your theme, not a specific issue with backslashes in JS/jQuery. To help you we need to know how the `href` of the clicked link is being used in the code

Comment: Thats a forward slash

Comment: The author is using a regex somewhere.. It is not a backslash "\" but a forward slash which is used by regex

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan would that be within the custom.js file? https://pastebin.com/AcrYsCqn

Comment: You'd have to provide the javaScript that goes along with the theme. There's not enough information to debug this error.

Comment: @Luke I've edited to add the custom.js file where I think the issue is.

Answer (score -4):

This is a probably Bootstrap issue. Try to use `data-target` attribute on your links like this

```
<a href="#/about-us" data-target="#about-us" class="nav-link">About</a>
```

Comment: This is not his problem. His problem is using a forward slash and the author of his theme uses regex or something similar and he doesn't have an escape character

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue. Someone else said its to do with the javascript I've added the custom.js file to the original post.